# Circuit Considerations

Tags: design, schematics, circuit-design

Note: Can skip all images except last, which is a schematic created using the editor.

I am at a point in the design process where I have created a schematic of the circuit that I want to create. I am using a buck converter to step down a 24V DC battery to 5V and using that battery to power an arduino. This arduino is acting as a speed controller, using PWM and getting input from external switch to set the speed. The input from this switch will be programatically read to set the speed output. The 5V output signal from the arduino then gets run through an op-amp configured as a non-inverting amplifier and drives a motor. The schematic follows: [[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76t2e.jpg)

This is the first real circuit I have created, and I don't know where to go from here. It is more than likely that I have made a mistake somewhere or forgotten a part or some heat/power consideration, but I don't have the slightest idea (1) how I could check my circuit for those things or (2) how I would remedy them.

I was wondering how I could go about doing these things and improving my knowledge of electronics in this way. I apologize if this question is somewhat vague; however, I really respect this community and the years of experience you have in the field, and I was hoping that your insights would be valuable in this question, as I don't really know how I could make it more specific. Thanks.

EDIT 1: Ok, after suggestion I am replacing the op-amp with an n-channel MOSFET as follows (Edit 2: added a 10K pull-down resistor on the gate of the MOSFET): 
[image: The arduino analog out is biasing the transistor.]

EDIT 3: Added pull down resistor to schematic and flipped MOSFET: 
[image]

EDIT 4: Adding a full schematic (Edit 5: switched NMOS and Motor position):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdLO0v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is this a bad idea? I thought the effective result would be the same as an NPN transistor, but I am just more comfortable with op-amps.

Comment: My biggest doubt thus far about your circuit is whether or not the OP-Amp can actually source enough current to drive the motor you're using. You would be better off using a power MOSFET here. Place the motor between the drain and Vdd, ground the source, and send the PWM signal to the gate, keep the flyback diode. You'll need to find a power MOSFET with a low enough gate threshold to use the PWM signal directly from the Arduino.

Comment: Also, Be aware that you have a small oscillator going with the OP-Amp and the 3.6k resistor. Nothing insane, but it will vary the motor's performance quite a bit.

Comment: I see... I was thinking that the MOSFET wouldn't work because it only worked on or off, but I completely forgot about the PWM of the arduino! Will modify and update, thanks! Will the MOSFET be able to switch on and off quickly enough?

Comment: @louiemcconnell You'll need to add a pull down resistor to the gate of the MOSFET. This resistor should be large enough so that the Arduino isn't sinking a lot of current through it, but small enough so that the time constant from the FET gate capacitance and the resistor is much much less than the period of your PWM signal. Otherwise the FET will just stay charged and your motor will run all the time.

Comment: Is 10K sufficient for the pulldown?

Comment: @louiemcconnell. Almost funny. The mosfet switches on and off in less than 100nS at most. It will be the fastest device in the circuit.

Comment: I think you want to flip the position of the MOSFET and motor/diode. The bottom terminal of the fet is [source, not drain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET#/media/File:Mosfet_n-ch_circuit.svg).

Comment: @rdtsc does the last edit fix that problem?

Comment: Just put the motor/diode above the MOSFET and it should work. Now the fun part, picking a MOSFET that will work properly.

Comment: There's a built-in schematic editor on this site that's quick and easy to learn. The button is on the toolbar. There isn't a symbol for the motor so just use the lamp symbol (down at the bottom) and rename it as 'motor'. Double-click the elements to edit their properties.

Comment: @louiemcconnell. Could you please provide us with a new diagram once you have made the changes you mentioned. If the Arduino pin can handle the load, connect it to the mosfet gate with a 22 ohm resistor. Connect the same Arduino pin to a 330 ohm pulldown resistor.

Comment: Ok, used the schematic editor to create a new schematic with the changes. Anything else to change?

Comment: Regarding Edit 4: The mosfet should be an NMOS with source = GND and motor between drain and + 24 V. Like you have it now it will not work. Also 1n4148 will propably be destroyed unless the motor is very small, use a 1n4001 instead for a motor up to 1 A or so.

Comment: Are you **only** feeding the Arduino from the 5 V switched voltage ?? Then that is overkill and expensive, you can use a 7805 regulator instead as the Arduino takes less than 10 mA. Only if you use more than 50 mA or so, use a buck converter.

Comment: @FakeMoustache I would imagine the Arduino would be drawing more than 50mA if it is outputting 5V PWM, right?

Comment: @louiemcconnell: I tweaked the CircuitLabs schematic a little to compress the width. SE reduces it to a 640 pixel-wide image which makes large schematics difficult to read. Please check that I didn't introduce any errors. +1 for a good detailed question. Please add some text in under the schematic explaining what S1 and the resistors are supposed to be doing. It looks unusual so you may be misunderstanding something.

Comment: @transistor Switch S1 is for an external input into the arduino, which will then change the speed on the speed control. This circuit is for the internals of an underwater scooter that has a switch (on/off) that has to control the speed (two clicks for up, one click for down). The arduino programatically reads this input and adjusts the speed via PWM accordingly.

Comment: The normal way to do the switch is to enable the input's internal pull-up resistor and just have the switch connect the pin to ground. One input. No resistors. Suggestion: one long click should turn the motor off.

Comment: @transistor Oh, that's a neat feature! I will do that. On the topic of user interface I am doing this for a friend who had some specific requests.

Comment: *I would imagine the Arduino would be drawing more than 50mA if it is outputting 5V PWM, right?* You are using only **one output** and if you look in the datasheet the maximum current for one output is 20 mA. But that output only has a 10k resistor and the gate of an NMOS there. At the ~400 Hz PWM frequency maybe 1 mA will flow there, not much more. And the rest of the MCU will **never** consume more than a few mA. So the supply current for the Arduino will be **far less than 50 mA**. So again: the switching converter is overkill, you do not need it here, it overcomplicates things.

Comment: @FakeMoustache but (24 - 5)V * 20mA would be almost 0.4 watts, which might be significant?

Comment: 0.4 W is about what you can get away with on a 7805 mounted on a small heatsink. **But** it is not going to supply 20 mA I am estimating that the supply current needed by the Arduino will be less than 10 mA so you will not even need a heatsink. You do not have any LEDs or such around the Arduino but if you did, run them at 5 mA and the total supply current will be less than 10 mA for sure. If you don't believe me, go build one and measure it. It is CMOS logic, which is very power efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Your power supply concept makes sense (using a buck converter to make 5 V from 24 V), but your motor driver needs work.

The voltage follower you show in your second schematic won't deliver much voltage to the motor.  The FET will likely need a few volts G-S to turn on enough to allow useful motor current.  With the gate at 5 V, that leaves very little to the motor.  It also uses the 24 V supply very inefficiently.  Most of the power will go into heating the FET, not running the motor.

Your third schematic makes no sense at all.  A flipped N channel MOSFET has a internal diode from source to drain, so the motor will always be on with over 23 V on it, and regardless of what you do with the gate.

I would use a N channel MOSFET as a low side switch.  Connect the motor between its drain and the 24 V supply, and don't forget the Schottky flyback catch diode in reverse across the motor.  Use PWM to set the effective motor voltage.  For example, if the motor is supposed to run from 6 V, then use 25% duty cycle.  This is also much more efficient.

Something like the IRLML0030 can be driven directly from the 5 V PWM output of the microcontroller.  At 40 mΩ, it will only dissipate 40 mW with 1 A thru it.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I made the changes you mentioned. Will the new schematic work?

Comment: @louie: The schematic seems clear enough, so I'd say it works.  That does not mean, of course, that the circuit will work.